# aws IoT: register-ca-certificate with cdk

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, aws-iot

I am using aws CDK and need to register an IoT CA certificate to be used to sign device certificates. At the moment I am doing this manually AFTER the deployment using

```
aws iot register-ca-certificate \
    --ca-certificate file://rootCA.pem \
    --verification-cert file://verificationCert.pem
```

However, doing this manually for multiple stages/accounts sounds tedious. Can this be handeled within the cdk stack itself? In the documentation I only found the `new iot.CfnCertificate()` class which can be used to declare a given X.509 certificate using a Ca certificate, but I would like to register a ca certificate itself.

Comment: I believe you can with CfnCACertificateProps. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_iot.CfnCACertificateProps.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the [RegisterCaCertificate](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/apireference/API_RegisterCACertificate.html) API has no CloudFormation (and therefore no CDK) equivalent.

CDK [CustomResources](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib-readme.html#custom-resources) are designed to fill such gaps in CloudFormation coverage.  The [AwsCustomResource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.custom_resources.AwsCustomResource.html) construct is the Custom Resource flavour to choose when you simply need to execute an AWS SDK call during the deploy lifecycle, as in your case.